# Passing parameters to popup dialog

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm passing an id from one component to another and face this error.

“cannot read property ”id" of null"

--> parent route (/order.component)

- I have a button called Make payment and navigate by using the code below

```
[routerLink]="['/order/payment'];
```

--> other route (/order-payment.component) -> not sure how to register this as child routes. I navigate to the order-payment page by using routerLink as shown above

Once, i reach the payment page. I like to pass the order id to the modal dialog to do some processing by clicking on Pay button.

Using routerLink again,

```
[routerLink]="['/', 'order', { outlets: { popup: order.id + '/payment'} }]"
```

After clicking on Pay button, this appears in my url:

order/(payment//popup:3/processPayment)

**route.ts**

```
export const OrderRoute: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: OrderComponent,
    resolve: {
        pagingParams: JhiResolvePagingParams
    },
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
        defaultSort: 'id,asc',
        pageTitle: ''
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
{
    path: ':id/view',
    component: OrderDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
        order: OrderResolve
    },
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
        pageTitle: ''
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},

{
    path: ':id/processPayment',
    component: PaymentPopupComponent,
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
        pageTitle: ''
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
    outlet: 'popup'
}
```

Order page

- Button ([routerLink]="['/order/payment'];)

Payment page

- Button ([routerLink]="['/', 'order', { outlets: { popup: order.id + '/payment'} }]")

Answer (score 1):

You can access the :id parameter in the PaymentPopupComponent by using the activated route

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
id = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path;
// or
this.route.params.subscribe((param) => {
    this.id = param.id; 
})
```

Or something similar.